# How to stop the Music app from lowering volume while in background?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app

When I'm playing music in the built-in Music app (metro) and switch out of it, the volume lowers almost completely. Besides docking it in a "split-view", how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck option `Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device` from the Advanced tab in audio properties window and restart PC

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either; neither on my desktop or on my Surface Pro 2.

Comment: it worked for me.
You have to restart Windows 8 / 8.1 for this to take effect. (Using simply "apply" or "save and close" does not work.) Thanks :-)